# Why is ethanol distilled off before adding water in the first step of a malonic synthesis?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, alcohols, distillation

I am doing a malonic synthesis shown below, and I wonder why I should distill ethanol off before adding water in the first step of the reaction (First I add absolute ethanol and solid sodium).[image]

Comment: I see no reason to distill off EtOH before adding water for the base hydrolysis step. The EtOH facilitates the reaction as the butyl malonate is readily soluble in it but not in water.

Comment: I think it is because of this http://www.passmyexams.co.uk/GCSE/chemistry/carboxylic-acids-reaction-alcohol.html i.e alcohol will react with your product (carboxylic acid) to form an ester.

Comment: Could you clear up the confusion and detail steps in more detail. Your reactions don't indicate when you boil off the ethanol...

Comment: I think the $\ce{KOH}$ hydrolysis is not necessary. Acid hydrolysis would do it. It is necessary to remove ethanol to prevent resterification (Le Chatelier's principle).

Comment: related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/37195/102629

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is a real procedure for actual synthesis.

Distilling ethanol off does have an effect on the workup of this reaction. Usually one needs to separate the reaction product and educts or side products afterwards by separation between an aqueous and an organic phase. Having ethanol in the mixture prevents the two phases from separating. In order to isolate your product you will need to distill ethanol off before adding water, because water would also be distilled off, if you added it first.

Comment: I disagree. You remove the ethanol after the base hydrolysis.

Comment: Where does it say the ethanol is distilled off after base hydrolysis?

Comment: It doesn't. My point is that it makes little sense to remove the EtOH before the base hydrolysis, all you need do is add some water and an excess of KOH to conduct the hydrolysis, then concentrate as the first part of the workup.

Comment: If you distill it off before, then do the hydrolysis, you can isolate your acid by acidifying your solution and extraction with apolar solvent. I think you just have a different procedure that you like to stick to, but OP describes the procedure like i explained.

Answer (score 0):

The synthesis adds two carbon units from malonic acid to butyl bromide, followed by a de-carboxylation step, to form caproic acid.

There are 2 reasons:

1. Water and alcohol form an azeotrope, why not recover some absolute ethanol before the second step?

 2. Reflux temperature for de-esterification will be higher with a greater percentage of water as ethanol is removed.

Butyl bromide boils around 101 C, so it can be distilled off during KOH reflux.  A possible by-product, n-butanol, which boils at 117 C but forms an azeotrope with H2O at 92 C, can also be removed with higher temperatures.

So, alcohols and butyl bromide could be fractionally distilled off during the KOH de-esterification (this technique would be practiced on a lab scale to perfect it), leaving the water soluble malonate adduct for subsequent decarboxylation.

Interestingly, after decarboxylation step, caproic acid could then be extracted back into non-polar solvent for further purification.